# Cesium polyline is not rendering, when state variable changes

Tags: reactjs, cesiumjs

### I am using **React**, **Cesium** and **Resium** as a `Cesium` wrapper

#### Code:

```js
import React,{useState,useEffect} from "react";
import { Viewer } from "resium";
import * as Resium from "resium";
import * as Cesium from 'cesium';
import flightData from "./data";
const terrainProvider = Cesium.createWorldTerrain();
const sleep = (ms) =>{
    return new Promise((res)=>{
      setTimeout(()=>res(),ms);
    })
}

const positions = [];
flightData.map(dataPoint=>{
    positions.push(dataPoint.longitude);
    positions.push(dataPoint.latitude);
    positions.push(dataPoint.height);
});

const ResiumComp=()=>{
    let viewer;
    const [posModel, setPosModel] = useState(null);
    const [airplaneUri, setAirplaneUri] = useState(null);
    const handleReady = tileset => {
        if (viewer) {
          //viewer.zoomTo(tileset);
        }
    };

    const airPlaneURI = async() => {
        const uri = await Cesium.IonResource.fromAssetId(246327)
        setAirplaneUri(uri);
    };

    const movePlane = async() =>{
        airPlaneURI();
        for(let i=0; i<flightData.length; i++){
            const dataPoint = flightData[i];
            const position = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(dataPoint.longitude, dataPoint.latitude, dataPoint.height);
            setPosModel(position);
            await sleep(100);
        }
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        Cesium.Ion.defaultAccessToken = process.env.REACT_APP_CESIUM_TOKEN;
        movePlane();
    },[]);

    return <Viewer
    full terrainProvider={terrainProvider}
    ref={e=>{
        viewer = e && e.cesiumElement;
    }}
    style={{
        position: "absolute",
        top: 0,
        left: 100,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 100,
      }}
    >
        {/* <Resium.Cesium3DTileset url={Cesium.IonResource.fromAssetId(5714)} onReady={handleReady}/> */}
        {
            flightData.map((dataPoint,idx)=>{
                const position = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(dataPoint.longitude, dataPoint.latitude, dataPoint.height);
                return <>
                        <Resium.Entity 
                            key={`point-${idx}`}
                            name="Tokyo" 
                            description = {`Location: (${dataPoint.longitude}, ${dataPoint.latitude}, ${dataPoint.height})`}
                            position={position}
                        >
                            <Resium.PointGraphics pixelSize={10} />
                        </Resium.Entity>
                    </>
            })
        }
        {/* polyline */}
        <Resium.Entity>
            <Resium.PolylineGraphics
                show
                width={3}
                material={Cesium.Color.RED}
                positions={Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArrayHeights(positions)}
            />
        </Resium.Entity>
        {/* Model */}
        {
            (airplaneUri&&posModel)&&<Resium.Entity
                tracked 
                position={posModel}
            >
                <Resium.ModelGraphics
                    scale={1}
                    uri={airplaneUri}
                    minimumPixelSize={100}
                    runAnimations
                    show
                    color={Cesium.Color.WHITE}
                />
            </Resium.Entity>
        }
    </Viewer>
}
export default ResiumComp;
```

Here `PolylineGraphics` is not rendering. When i inspected the code then i got that, the issue is appearing due to a change in the state variable.

So, when i comment down the line `setPosModel(position);`, then polyline is rendering.

Change the folowing function code

```js
 const movePlane = async() =>{
        airPlaneURI();
        for(let i=0; i<flightData.length; i++){
            const dataPoint = flightData[i];
            const position = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(dataPoint.longitude, dataPoint.latitude, dataPoint.height);

            // after commenting this line, there is no issue
            //setPosModel(position);
            await sleep(100);
        }
    }
```

The polyline graphics should render in any case, but i am not able to figure it out.

#### [Public git repositery link](https://github.com/ats1999/rahul-react-map-gl-cluster/tree/main/react-map-gl-cluster)

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not related to cesium/resium, but to react itself.
Notice that inside your `useEffect()` method you call to `movePlane()`, which then calls for `setPosModel(position)` - a state changing function, which will re-render the app, which will call `useEffect()`... 
 Get where i'm going to?

There are several solutions to stop your app from re-rendering infinietly. The simplest one is to follow react recommendations and wrap `movePlane` inside a `useCallback()` hook, like so:

```
const movePlane = useCallback(() => async() =>{
        airPlaneURI();
        for(let i=0; i<flightData.length; i++){
            const dataPoint = flightData[i];
            const position = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(dataPoint.longitude, dataPoint.latitude, dataPoint.height);
        setPosModel(position);
        await sleep(100);
    }
}, [])
```

Of course, you'll also have to add `movePlane` to the dependencies array of `useEffect()`:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    Cesium.Ion.defaultAccessToken = process.env.REACT_APP_CESIUM_TOKEN;
    movePlane();
},[movePlane]);
```

**Sidenote:** There are many issues that you need to consider with your code! 
For example, why is `setPosModel()` being called after **each iteration** of you for loop? As much as I can see, `flightData` is a HUGE array, you should probably fix that too

Comment: `a state changing function, which will re-render the app, which will call useEffect()` if i do `useEffect(()=>{
    Cesium.Ion.defaultAccessToken = process.env.REACT_APP_CESIUM_TOKEN;
    movePlane(); console.log("useeffect")
},[movePlane]);` then this is being printed only once. This means useEffect is being called only once after the component mounts to the DOM.

Comment: `which will re-render the app` this is true it'll re-render the app.

Comment: this syntax worked `useCallback(() => async() =>`,

Comment: But, still we have performance issue, line is being rendered every time.

Comment: I think spliting the components will work